# master page file issue

Tags: css, sharepoint-2007, user-interface, master-pages

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have a root web site and some child sub-web site. I am using Blueband.master and related css files (e.g. Band.css).

My question is, for my parent site and child site, are they using the same master page files (including css files) or using different master page files (including css files) -- if they are using different ones, how to find which master page files (including css files) root site and child site are using? I ask this question is because I find some modifications of root web site does not apply to child site.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

To find out which master page they are using you can iterate (programmatically through each site, and output it to the screen.

I HATE the way Sharepoint handles this.  Normally each time you make changes to the root master page you need to re-force all the subsites to use the same master page - even if you have already done so.  I ended up writing an httpmodule based on the link below to allow me to specify any master page I want - with the added effect of allowing me to style the much maligned application.master.  With a little tweaking you can set up replace rules in the web.config to allow you to have different master pages for different subsites.

have a look at http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx